# Surfaces and solids

Tags: geometry

If each edge of a cube measures x^2 (x squared), write a simplified formula for its surface area. How would I write the formula? I know that surface area for a regular prism is lateral area + 2 (base area)

Answer (score 1):

Um, since a cube has $6$ faces all congruent:  $6x^2$

==== correction =====

Oops. I misread the the question.  I thought the side was $x$ and the face was $x^2$.

Instead it's that the side itself  was $x^2$ (not $x$).

So the face is $(x^2)^2 = x^4$.

And as there are $6$ faces, surface area is $6x^4$.

=== by the way

" I know that surface area for a regular prism is lateral area + 2 (base area)"

And you can use this.  Lateral area = $4*face$ and $base = face$ so surface area = $4*face + 2*face = 6*face$.

Comment: Nope. The side itself is $x^2$, so the area of the cube is $6(x^2)^2=6x^4$.

Comment: Oh,  I misread the original question.  But please, when you edit an answer edit the typing and formatting but don't change the answer.  If the poster *meant* "blah" then that's what he meant, even if it is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** A cube has six faces. Each face has the same area. Each face is a square. The area of a square with side $s$ is $s^2$. Now put it all together.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: btw, why do you want an edge as $x^2?$.. sounds strange.

Comment: I don't want it, OP specified it. My guess is that this is just an exercise in algebra and simplification of expressions involving powers of monomials.